# Ошибка : illegal break statement

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = prompt("Login: ");

if (a == "GeoGame") {
  alert("press Ok");

} else {
  alert("Wrong Login");
  break;
}

var c = prompt("Password");

if (c == "2564GGT456") {
  alert("George Gamer   Login: GeoGame    Bank: 200,567.56$   Нажмите OK что бы снять деньги.");
  alert("Деньги уcпешно перечислены на ваш аккаунт");
} else {
  alert("Wrong Password");
}
```

Comment: "message": "SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch
, написано где можно использовать бреак

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно работать

```
(function () {
    var a = prompt("Login: ");

    if (a == "GeoGame") {
        alert("press Ok");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong Login");
        return;
    }

    var c = prompt("Password");
    if (c == "2564GGT456") {
        alert("George Gamer   Login: GeoGame    Bank: 200,567.56$   Нажмите OK что бы снять деньги.");
        alert("Деньги уcпешно перечислены на ваш аккаунт");
    } else {
        alert("Wrong Password");
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

А какой `break` в операторе `if`? `break` можно вставлять либо внутри цикла, либо в операторе `switch`.

Можете вынести весь код в функцию и вместо `break` использовать `return`

Answer (score 0):

можете использовать return false заместо break;